# how to add elements to a pointer char array?

Tags: c

**Introduction**

I'm trying to iterate over a buffer and copy it's contents into a pointer array. the end goal is to split each word into their own buffers. Here is the code. (it's not complete and only a snippet.)

**Code**

```
char *buf = "install-pkg argument1";
char *first_phrase;

for(int i=0; i<strlen(buf); i++)
{
      if(buf[i] != " ")
         first_phrase += buf[i]; //***incorect?***

      else if(buf[i] == " ")
         break;   
}
```

**The problem**

It compiles with no errors or warnings. However when i run the program i get a *segmentation fault*. So i'm accessing memory my process does not have access to and i'm guessing i'm copying the contents of the first buffer to the 2nd incorrectly?

Comment: I see no pointer array in your code, only a couple of individual pointers.  And one of them is used while uninitialized.

Comment: `char *first_phrase` has not been allocated any memory using malloc so doing `first_phrase += buf[i];` is resulting in segmentation fault.

Comment: @guarav: why?  `first_phrase` is uninitialized, but incrementing a pointer normaly won't segfault even if the pointer is uninitialized. (Technically, it's UB. But mist architectures these days don't care about the bit pattern of a pointer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several faults in your code snippet

1) Comparison - surprised you didn't get any warnings on this.

```
if (buff[i] != " ")
if (buff[i] == " ")
```

Compares a character against a string.  This will not work.  It needs to be changed to

```
if (buff[i] != ' ')
if (buff[i] == ' ')
```

2) As mentioned in the comments, the space in first_phrase must be allocated before you can add to it

```
first_phrase = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);
```

Allocate the same size as your input string just in case there are no spaces in the string.  Add 1 for the string terminator

3) Concatenating to the string needs a counter.  The += adds to the pointer so all you are doing is moving first_phrase by a size but not actually adding to its content.  Something like

```
int fp = -1;
...
for ...
    if (buff[i] != ' ')
        first_phrase[++fp] = buff[i];
```

4) At the end of the loop, first_phrase needs to be terminated

```
first_phrase[++fp] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not copying anything at all in that snippet.

```
first_phrase += buf[i];
```

Adds the (integer code) of the i-th character in buf to the uninitialised pointer `first_phrase`. Adding a random number to an unitialised variable is meaningless but it's not illegal.

Trying to see what an unitialised pointer happens to point at *is* illegal, because the pointer doesn't point at anything.¹ You probably do that later in your code, at which point your program will segfault (if you're lucky).

---

¹ And the fact that it's been incremented to some other unspecified value doesn't make it more or less legal.